# Eclipse and Android sharing resources

Tags: android, build, android-resources

Beginners question:
I have one Library project, that has files under raw, drawable, etc.
I have added a reference to it in my project that has other raw, drawable etc.

I see the java files from the library project but not the resources (raw, drawable, etc.).

How do I add them?
I tried with "Link Source", but I can't add raw to raw (and I need to use same name for directory, right?)

IN other words: how do I merge the resources from the Library project to my main project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are automatically merged, you dont have to worry about it, if you have a resource with the same name in the project's folder, it takes priority over the library resources. Have a look at here

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject